# Is there any api in the wordpress to get the view count of posts. I mean without using any plugins

Tags: wordpress

For eg : https://ww.abcd.com/news/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/007
will give all the details about the post with id 007 but not the view count of that post,similarly it doesn't also give the images that are included in that post.

Any ideas how to get those details without using any external plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it this way:

1) - add this code to the `functions.php` of your wordpress theme

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

2) - This part of the tracking views code will set the post views. Just place this snippet below within the `single.php` inside the wordpress loop

```
setPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

3) - to display the view count:

```
echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: thanks bro,as i can understand i have to paste the "**echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());**" everytime in the jsp/html where ever i have to show the view. can't it be made like a url which takes the post id and give me the view count of the post ?

Comment: you can add this getPostViews(get_the_ID()) to your url and please accept my answer if you think it helped you

Comment: Wont work for caching with W3 Total Cache, etc.  Change my mind.